# Images and text coming out in a different order to how I expected

Tags: r, r-markdown

My initial issue was trying to get captions to be displayed in the pdf output, which I think I have now worked out how to solve.  But in the process, my test markdown file has thrown up another issue that I don't understand.

I have a rmarkdown file that looks exactly like this:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Nicole Avison"
date: "Monday, March 23, 2015"
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: yes
---
# Title 1  

![Image 1 caption](Images/picture1.png)

Text...  

# Title 2  

![Image 2 caption](Images/picture2.png)

# Title 3  

Some text here  

![Image 3 caption](Images/picture3.png)

Some more text here
```

When I click on 'knit pdf' in R Studio, the pdf output has things in a different order to how I expected given the order I have written them in the rmarkdown file:

```
1 Title 1
[Image 1]
Figure 1: Image 1 caption
Text...
2 Title 2
3 Title 3
Some text here
Some more text here
[Image 2]
Figure 2: Image 2 caption
[Image 3]
Figure 3: Image 3 caption
```

Is this something because of the way I have experimented to get the captions working and it's sort of remembered old changes?  Or is this something I am doing funny?

When I put the changes into my original proper document so that the captions would show (which they do) I also had this odd changing of order :(  Only with the final caption in that case though, the others were in the right place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be more of a LaTex question. Your captions should be fine, but LaTex is saying that it can't put the two images in the same first page, and so it puts the second image on the page, and then the headings go all wonky. If you only plan on compiling to pdf, write raw tex code where you need to. I provide a quick example below. Note that it really doesn't solve the problem, but it may give you more control over object placement (e.g. the `[h!]` after `\begin{figure}` tries to force figure placement). You can also control figure width in the width argument of `\includegraphics` (the 0.75 says scale the image down to be 75% of the full text width. Sorry if this isn't complete, but I hope it helps.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Nicole Avison"
date: "Monday, March 23, 2015"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
---
# Title 1  

![Image 1 caption](image1.jpg)

Text...  

# Title 2  

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{image2.jpg}
\caption{Image 2 caption}
\end{figure}

# Title 3  

Some text here  

![Image 3 caption](image3.jpg)

Some more text here
```